# raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool with '#{spec_name}' found." unless pool LOCALHOST3000 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

```
  def retrieve_connection(spec_name) #:nodoc:
    pool = retrieve_connection_pool(spec_name)
    raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool with '#{spec_name}' found." unless pool
    pool.connection
  end
```

I am working on a web app from scratch and found lots of errors in the ruby on rails code above. I installed all the gems required and install and connected home page in controller and route.rb but I can't find the solution for this problem.

```
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1009:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Please explain your question short and simple manner thanks

Comment: Is your database running?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `database.yml` file for invisible characters that might be throwing off the spacing. That'll produce the error you're referencing.